# JavaScript convert callback to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

I would like to convert the following callback procedure to a promise. I have the following:

```
app.get('/api/books', function(req, res)
{
  let booksCallback = function(books)
  {
    res.send(books)
  }
  DataBase.getBooks(booksCallback)

})
```

And then:

```
getBooks : function(booksCallback)
{
  database.ref('/books/').once('value', function(datasnapshot)
  {
    var books = datasnapshot.val()
    booksCallback(books)

  });
}
```

So I'm sending the callback function as a parameter to the function getBooks, which does an async call to Firebase. But is there any way I could do something like `Database.getBooks().then(res.send(books))`? But then I would need the variable books returned from the async function in getBooks first. Can this be done with a Promise?

Comment: you could wrap the function in `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})`

Comment: `on('value',` - is that likely to "fire" more than once for each call to `getBooks` - if so, promises wont help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return a promise from your getBooks function.

```
getBooks : function()
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.ref('/books/').on('value', (datasnapshot) => { 
            var books = datasnapshot.val(); 
            books ? resolve(books) : reject();
        });
    });  
}
```

And you can use it, in this way...

```
app.get('/api/books', function(req, res)
{  
  DataBase.getBooks()
   .then((books) => res.send(books))
   .catch(() => console.log('!!. ERROR'));
})
```

Comment: Great, the catch you put on res.send(), does it print the error message if the send failed, or if the books variable is null?

Comment: the catch it not set in res.send is in this way... then().catch()... but if res.send fails the console log will be shown, and also if getBooks() rejects the promise.

Comment: @JuliusvM Both. If you want to handle only the rejection from `getBooks`, then use [`.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)